web3.js Keccak256 giving different answer
Minimum reproducible example :
hash1 = "be516d52220ea58966754101dd7ee25be73a695febd2bca54145681e2cc72fe9"
hash2 = "edede15ad23aba32fd2613ffee105278e322b2d81314bcb66eb4c453ad072bd4"
const hash = web3.utils.keccak256('string', hash1+hash2);
console.log(hash) 

Output:
0x97fc46276c172633607a331542609db1e3da793fca183d594ed5a61803a10792
Output using online tool :
87d7fd470f849d4476228290ca1bf8e089e7e1635c5c57872eb1e3c65746be71
https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html?input_type=hex&input=be516d52220ea58966754101dd7ee25be73a695febd2bca54145681e2cc72fe9edede15ad23aba32fd2613ffee105278e322b2d81314bcb66eb4c453ad072bd4&output_type=hex
Also while hashing to find transactionRootHash is it KEC256(concatenation_of_2_Hashes) OR is it KEC256(hex_addition_of_2_hashes) ?
Thank you .

If you would like to generate the same hash as the one that you're getting from the online tool, then here's the code for that:
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

const hash1 = "be516d52220ea58966754101dd7ee25be73a695febd2bca54145681e2cc72fe9";
const hash2 = "edede15ad23aba32fd2613ffee105278e322b2d81314bcb66eb4c453ad072bd4";
const hash = Web3.utils.keccak256('0x' + hash1 + hash2);
console.log(hash); // With 0x prefix
console.log(hash.replace('0x', '')); // Without 0x prefix

With respect to your second question:

Also while hashing to find transactionRootHash is it
KEC256(concatenation_of_2_Hashes) OR is it
KEC256(hex_addition_of_2_hashes) ?

I think @Maka has explained the same in detail quite well in his answer.

A few things:
>>> w3.solidity_keccak(['bytes'],[bytes.fromhex(hash1+hash2)])
HexBytes('0x87d7fd470f849d4476228290ca1bf8e089e7e1635c5c57872eb1e3c65746be71')

Encode bytes, from hex.
To get the Merkle root

concat hex str
swap the bytes
double hash

Plagiarised from a classic example:

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/blocks/btc/100000

root: f3e94742aca4b5ef85488dc37c06c3282295ffec960994b2c0d5ac2a25a95766
>>> h1
'8c14f0db3df150123e6f3dbbf30f8b955a8249b62ac1d1ff16284aefa3d06d87'
>>> h2
'fff2525b8931402dd09222c50775608f75787bd2b87e56995a7bdd30f79702c4'
>>> h3
'6359f0868171b1d194cbee1af2f16ea598ae8fad666d9b012c8ed2b79a236ec4'
>>> h4
'e9a66845e05d5abc0ad04ec80f774a7e585c6e8db975962d069a522137b80c1d'

# for more on network byte order see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
def byte_swap(_hash : str) -> str:
  return ''.join(reversed(list(
    map(lambda x : _hash[x:x+2], range(0, len(_hash), 2))
  )))

def concat_and_hash(hA : str, hB : str) -> str:
  import hashlib
  # concat hex str and convert to bytes
  _hash = bytes.fromhex(hA+hB)
  # double hash bytes and return hex string
  return hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(_hash).digest()).digest().hex() 

>>> byte_swap(concat_and_hash(concat_and_hash(byte_swap(h1),byte_swap(h2)), concat_and_hash(byte_swap(h3),byte_swap(h4))))
'f3e94742aca4b5ef85488dc37c06c3282295ffec960994b2c0d5ac2a25a95766'

credit:

https://medium.com/@stolman.b/1-4-hashing-transactions-txids-to-find-the-merkle-root-3aa5255f8de8


This is not working . Tried this for block 1000000 of ethereum .
 

H=[
"ea1093d492a1dcb1bef708f771a99a96ff05dcab81ca76c31940300177fcf49f",
"e9e91f1ee4b56c0df2e9f06c2b8c27c6076195a88a7b8537ba8313d80e6f124e",
]
resHash=byte_swap(concat_and_hash(byte_swap(H[0]),byte_swap(H[1])))

`resHash` - `a24db1af4dcd29255ed7ac1bbd51e590e97a1eadecd60d67731c2ddb11138f6f`

Actual `transactionsRoot` - `0x65ba887fcb0826f616d01f736c1d2d677bcabde2f7fc25aa91cfbc0b3bad5cb3`
